# jquery delay is happening after fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm fading in and out 3 divs. the fadein and out works great, except the delay is happening after the div is faded out. the code:

```
runslide();

function runslide() {
    $('.expect').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $('.marketing').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $('.consider').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                runslide();
            });
        })
    });
}
```

here is the file I am working on: http://goo.gl/8xt1XZ , it is the slider after the text.

Comment: I created a simple fiddle based on your site but it seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/d4xbN/1/ Can you post any CSS you have for the slides?

Comment: delay doesn't works with animations

Comment: @sbaaaang - so what does it work with, if not animations ?

Comment: @Mathias I don't have any css that controls the slides, just for fonts/colors etc. do you think that is relevant? I'm hiding the slides first using this" '`.expect, .marketing, .consider{ display:none }` .

Comment: and fiddle is working for me too. do you think my code is clashing with something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are doing something with royalSlider in your page. Have you tried removing that so that it doesn't affect your own animations.

Comment: royalslider is being used to slide in the videos and I tried removing that. the fade in still doesn't work..

Comment: You are using the classes "royalSlider" and "rsDefault" for the div containing your slides. Try renaming them to something unrelated to royalSlider to make sure there are no collisions.

Comment: still the same. I just uploaded the updated file without the royalslider classes.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
runslide();

function runslide() {
$('.expect').fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(2000, function() {
$('.marketing').fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $('.consider').fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    runslide();
});
})
});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/83S3M/4/)

Comment: Yeah, removing all the delays would solve the issue, I just don't think it was what the OP was after here.

Comment: @adeneo me too dont have the exact idea about what is in his mind. Let him check this.. :)

Comment: sorry I'm late! I want the slides to stay a while before fading out. the exact opposite is happening. the current slide fades out, the place stays blank and then another one appears. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The delay seems to be working fine.  You do have a missing semicolon but I don't think that's the problem.  I'm not sure what the problem is on your site. I tried it with jQuery version 1 and 2 and both seems to be working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/5t4rL/2/

```
$('.expect').hide();
$('.marketing').hide();
$('.consider').hide();
runslide();

function runslide() {
    $('.expect').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $('.marketing').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $('.consider').fadeIn(1500).delay(7500).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                runslide();
            });
        });
    });
}
```